# can we do delete or update in a GET method?

Tags: get

We all know that GET method is to retrive information from the server while the POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource, for example, update a table. However, can we do update in a GET method??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation language (availability of DB library) and access rights to the database, you can do anything you like in a GET request. Retrieving in GET and updating with POST requests is just an agreement and usually not enforced by the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can do operation like POST,PUT,PATCH in GET method.
But it's not a good practice because it is breaking the purpose of GET method.

If you see REST principles, a GET request should be used for retrieving data and should be idempotent, meaning it should not change the state of the server. As per the HTTP specification, GET requests are intended for safe and read-only operations.

If am wrong correct it.